# What is the wrong with the sql syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, syntax-error

```
SELECT 
    a.Name, a.About, 
    COUNT(b.Id) AS TotalCities, 
    SUM(b.NoOfDwellers) AS TotalCityDwellers 
FROM 
    Countries a 
LEFT JOIN 
    Cities b ON a.Id = b.CountryId 
WHERE 
    a.Name LIKE '%some str%'  
GROUP BY 
    a.Id 
ORDER BY 
    a.Name ASC
```

This SQL returns error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Countries.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If you have a `SELECT` which has a `GROUP BY` clause, **every** column in the `SELECT` list must be *either* an aggregate (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX` etc.), or then it has to be in the `GROUP BY` clause. You have both  `a.Name` and `a.About` in your `SELECT` list which are **not** handled by an aggregate - therefore, **these two** columns **must** appear in the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Exactly what the error message sais: `Countries.Name` is not contained in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Not knowing your data, this may be as simple as just replacing `a.Name` with `MAX(a.Name)` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: But it is possible in mysql. So how can I achieve this query result using sql server 2012.@marc_s & @TT

Comment: @Chayan - it's a [documented *extension* in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html) and a not terribly good one (IMO).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` clause, every column in the `SELECT` list of columns must be **either** an aggregate (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX` etc.), or then it has to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You have both `a.Name` and `a.About` in your `SELECT` list which are not handled by an aggregate - therefore, these two columns must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT 
    a.Name, a.About, 
    COUNT(b.Id) AS TotalCities, 
    SUM(b.NoOfDwellers) AS TotalCityDwellers 
FROM 
    Countries a 
LEFT JOIN 
    Cities b ON a.Id = b.CountryId 
WHERE 
    a.Name LIKE '%some str%'  
GROUP BY 
    a.Id, a.About, a.Name 
ORDER BY 
    a.Name ASC
```

Comment: Now it shows: `Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.`

Comment: @Chayan: `TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` are **deprecated** and **should not** be used ever - use `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead, or use an appropriately sized `(N)VARCHAR(n)` instead of just using `VARCHAR(MAX)` for everything. ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna accept this answers after few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

In a query contains a `group by` clause, every row in the result represents the entire group of rows that share the same value(s) of the column(s) they are grouped by. Therefore, every item you select must either be one of those columns, a row-based manipulation on them, or an aggregate function. It seems that you're trying to aggregate `b`'s values according to `a`'s `name` and `about`. If this is true, you should amend your `group by` clause accordingly:

```
SELECT 
    a.Name, a.About, 
    COUNT(b.Id) AS TotalCities, 
    SUM(b.NoOfDwellers) AS TotalCityDwellers 
FROM 
    Countries a 
LEFT JOIN 
    Cities b ON a.Id = b.CountryId 
WHERE 
    a.Name IS NULL 
GROUP BY 
    a.Name, a.About -- here!
ORDER BY 
    a.Name ASC
```